# How do I write this pseudocode in C++? Function returns two arrays to two initialized arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, list-initialization

I am trying to implement a bottom up approach function to the rod cutting problem and I need to use this particular pseudo-code from the CLRS textbook. In it there two functions and one calls the other in this fashion

`(r,s) = EXTENDED-BOTTOM-UP-CUT-ROD(p,n)`

Where r and s are two different arrays. The function also returns two arrays. I am currently using C++ and I've tried things such as

```
(r,s)=function(p,n);
[r,s]=function(p,n);
{r,s}=function(p,n);

//return statements follow similar attempts

return (r,s);
return {r,s};
return [r,s];
```

All these typically resulted in errors or incorrect outputs. Perhaps I shouldn't be using basic arrays for this implementation?

Comment: You shouldn't. Also look at structured binding.

Comment: Passing arrays around can be tricky because you have to be careful about how and where the memory is allocated, and you have to keep track of the size of the array yourself.  Since you're using C++, it should be easier to return `std::vector<T>`.  You can simply define a struct that holds two `std::vector<T>`  objects and return that struct from your function, instead of trying to invent new syntax for returning multiple values from a function.

Comment: There is no new syntax to invent, though. The choice of the struct versus structured binding would depend on how much sense either solution makes in the scheme of the larger problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tuples and "structured binding" in C++17 to return multiple values efficiently as below:

```
#include <tuple>
#invlude <vector>

std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int>> func_that_returns_two_vectors() {

   std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
   std::vector<int> v2 = {4, 5, 6};

   return {std::move(v1), std::move(v2)};

}

int main() {
    auto [v1, v2] = func_that_returns_two_vectors();
    return 0;
}
```

To do something similar pre-C++17 you can use `std::tie`.

Comment: Thank you, but curious question: my compiler gives a warning that -> " warning: decomposition declaration only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z". Is this just a compiler difference?